# Using linq with a PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, propertyinfo

Assuming this class:

```
class Foo 
{
    public string Bar {get; set;}
    public string Baz {get; set;}
}
```

How can I use reflection to query the following list:

```
List<Foo> list_of_foo = new List<Foo>() 
{
    new Foo() {Bar = "Hello", Baz = "Hola"} ,
    new Foo() {Bar = "World!", Baz = "Mundo!"}
};

// match is found, and will hold the Foo with "Hello" and "Hola"
var match = list_of_foo.Single (ob => ob.Bar.Equals("Hello"));

// ------ My Question -----

// Lets assume I get the property I Need at run time:
string get_at_runtime = "Baz";
var prop_info = typeof(Foo).GetProperty(get_at_runtime);

// I can use the prop_info on the "match" variable like this:
var some_var = prop_info.GetValue(match)    // some_var holds "Hola"

// But how can I do the following: 
var some_foo = list_of_foo.Single ( f => f.prop_info.equals("Mundo!"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
var some_foo = list_of_foo.Single(f => prop_info.GetValue(f).Equals("Mundo!"));
```

but this will be safer in case of property has `null` value:

```
var some_foo = list_of_foo.Single(f => "Mundo!".Equals(prop_info.GetValue(f)));
```

Comment: You ! absolutely correct. I was trying to access it like `Single(f => f.some_foo...)` and the autocomplete was suggesting it's not allowed. Obvisouly, what needs to be done is use the `f` like you suggested ... It must be time to get some rest. Been staring at this for over half an hour. Thank you. (and, seems like some of the images on the website in your contact aren't working :)

Comment: Amazing what some rest can do for you. Regarding your second comment, if you think a string might be `null` when comparing you can also use the static Equals like this: `string.Equals(prop_info.GetValue(f),"Mundo!")` which takes care of nulls